# desktop shortcut does not update when using a link to .desktop file

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-gnome, .desktop, shortcuts, desktop-icons

I created a desktop shortcut (`shortcut.desktop` exists in `~/Desktop`). If I edit `shortcut.desktop` and save the changes are immediately reflected in the shortcut. If I instead save `shortcut.desktop` to another directory (say my home dir) and create a link to that file in `~/Desktop` the shortcut still works but if I edit `shortcut.desktop` and save the shortcut is not updated. Is there any explanation as to why this is so?

Comment: I think only certain folders are observed for changes, in your case the relavant folder is `~/Desktop`. If you store the .desktop-file somewhere else and just place a link to the .desktop-file, the link will remain unchanged if you edit and save the .desktop-file, thus an update will not be triggered.

Comment: Even if it's a hard link it won't change? @mook765

Comment: Even with a hard-link it will not work, as far as I tested. I admit that I don't fully understand how the thing works behind the scene, it is pretty hard to find solid documentation about such topics.